# How to catch Spring PageNotFound exception in DispatcherServlet context without web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I'm trying to catch all spring MVC errors and display custom error page, to avoid presenting of native Tomcat page.

I was trying with several `@ExceptionHandler` like :

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
```

but the 404 is always translated to native Tomcat page (other exception mapings works).

My exception handlers in `@ControllerAdvice` are never called during requesting non existing URL, and i receive such log message:

```
o.s.w.s.PageNotFound WARN   - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/websandbox/asdas] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

**How to avoid fallback from spring context to native Tomcat error pages?**

My dispatcher servlet is mapped to `/` (not `/*`)

Not, that I'm not throwing custom exception - this exception is generated while requesting not mapped url like /knloqtnqklnwejlfnqw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I found the exact solution by diagnosing `DispatcherServlet` sources. We need to specify init-param for dispatcher servlet:

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

So, 404 is very specific case.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in Java code? I mean by using a class that `implements WebApplicationInitializer`?

Answer (score 0):

A resource that is not mapped will always get rejected at the deployment descriptor and it will be web.xml.

1. You need to configure the web.xml to throw these errors to a particular URL say /404
2. Now you need to map these url's to a controller that can take necessary actions.

[How to configure custom errors in Spring MVC](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/custom-error-404-error-page-in-spring-mvc.html) This article shows how you can do this.

I hope this is all that you need to do.

In case you want to use @ExceptionHandler for a class you can refer [this article](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc). However i didnt find it very convincing but still it will help you to map NOT_FOUND exceptions and others from controllers.